# Make a Href follow the URL in the address bar

Tags: html

How do you make a Href follow the URL in the address bar?

For example : If the URL in the address bar is `http://www.example.com/us` and my `href` is `href='/books'`, on clicking the link, the link leads to `http://www.example.com/books` and not `http://www.example.com/us/books`. How do I code the href to do this? I tried several methods, but unless I code it as `href='/us/books'` it will not work as expected.

Comment: Things are usually much less likely to break if you stick to root-relative URLs. I suggest you do that (i.e. just use `href="/us/books"`).

Comment: The alternative is to remove the first slash to make the href location relative. `href="books"`  But as @MattiVirkkunen indicated, this might lead to issues down the line.

Comment: Even when using `href="books"` it'll go to `http://www.example.com/books` I cannot understand why.

Comment: The domain in the address bar needs a `/` after the end. Only then will things work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways in which to do this, depending on the server configuration you're running your site on. The only sure way to do this in pure HTML is

```
<a href="/us/books/">Books</a>
```

Because URL links are resolved on the client side, and other configurations would complicate things (i.e. IIS Virtual applications)

If you're using ASP for a virtual application, try this:

```
<a href="<% Response.Write(Server.MapPath("~")); %>/Books">Books</a>
```

For other configurations, like PHP you could set a global constant like

```
define("US_ROOT_DIR", "/us");
```

And use it as

```
<a href="<?php echo US_ROOT_DIR; ?>/Books">Books</a>
```

But in the end, it really comes down to directory structure management since every project is different. Any way I hope this helps and if not I hope it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Still the same. Still go to `http://www.example.com/books` and not `http://www.example.com/us/books`

Comment: Oh, duh I don't know what I was thinking. That's what I get for trying to multitask. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.example.com/us">
</head>
```

then `href="/books"` will redirect to `href="http://www.example.com/us/books"`